# Lerna + TS: how to create type declaration using type declaration from another package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monorepo, lerna

I'm using lerna + typescript to build an NPM package.

I have the following structure

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── darpi
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   └── index.d.ts
│   └── schema
│       └── dist
│           └── index.d.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

The `darpi` package depends on the `schema` package types

`packages/schema/dist/index.d.ts`

```
// import types
import schema from './rules/schema'
import validate from './functions/validate'
import configure from './configure'

// and export
export { schema, validate, configure }
```

`packages/darpi/dist/index.d.ts`

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import type { schema, configure } from '@cataline.io/schema'

declare let Form: typeof defineComponent
declare let Field: typeof defineComponent
declare let Button: typeof defineComponent

export { Form, Field, Button, schema, configure }
```

the only package that actually goes to NPM is `darpi`

that is

`packages/darpi/package.json`

```json
{
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
  // ...
}
```

and then it gets published on NPM, when trying to make use of

`Form, Field, Button` they are OK

[image]

`configure` or `schema`, although they work fine, don't have type declarations

[image]

Typescript can't know the types that came from `@cataline.io/schema`, clearly because this is a private package resolved by lerna at development time

[image]

my question is:

> How to export types to NPM that comes from the private sibling packge?

I couldn't think of anything to fix it.

**`schema` must not be made a public package in NPM and then installed together with `darpi`, no. `darpi` works perfectly, I just need to solve the typing problem that comes from the sibling package.**

Comment: I think you should import from `@cataline.io/darpi`

Comment: @Seti 
actually I imported it correctly, I just wrote it wrong in the question, sorry. I updated the question and put new screenshots

Comment: If i understand correctly, only `/darpi` is in npm and `/schema` is not there, and you cannot import from it as it is not in node_modules... If yes, then you should build types from TS files, and import them into main package (and export them).  (Build .d.ts file?)

Comment: @Seti 
you are correct, but i am already doing exactly what you say.

`schema` exports types to be imported in `darpi` and exported again to be used by NPM users, as per the screenshots I sent